# await array; by implementing extension method for array

Tags: c#, async-await

I wanted to make an array awaitable by implementing an extension method

```
public static IAwaitable GetAwaiter(this mytype[] t)
{
    return t.First().GetAwaiter();
}
```

but even though IntelliSense says "(awaitable) `mytype[]`", the compiler gives me an error when using

```
mytype[] t = new mytype[] { new mytype(), new mytype() };
await t;
```

Calling await on a single object of mytype works fine. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: await is used on async calls, why are you using it with types ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: BTW: Using [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) seems to be better than implementing an awaitable class yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731815/asyncctp-creating-a-class-that-is-iawaitable

Comment: The error message is unfortunately just "Cannot await 'mytyope[]'". Thanks for pointing me to `TaskCompletionSource<T>` but there are special requirements...

Comment: @prthrokz He might be following [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx).

Comment: @David: I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. It's easier to deal with `Task`s than custom awaitables.

Comment: @Stephen+Daniel: We're writing an DES kernel which should use await instead of Threads for the different components' process methods for simulation; and last but not least we're translating the designed system to VHDL. So we want to have just the advantages/core functionality await brings along (something in the sense of "fibers" which are not supported in .Net 4.5) and don't want to have all the "taskish" overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the compiler and you should [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

I can verify that this code doesn't work (using `Task` and `TaskAwaiter`, not custom types):

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Task[] tasks)
{
    return tasks.First().GetAwaiter();
}

Task[] tasks = …;
await tasks;
```

(It produces the error "Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]'", as reported.)

But swapping array for `IEnumerable` (in both the the method and the local) does work:

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    return tasks.First().GetAwaiter();
}

IEnumerable<Task> tasks = …;
await tasks;
```

Interestingly, with the fixed version, awaiting an array directly still doesn't work. But for example awaiting `IList` does work.

Comment: I followed your advice and reported it (see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775990/await-array-by-implementing-extension-method-for-array-does-not-compile). Thanks for your investigation effort.